# AJP doesnt work with server alias

Tags: apache, jsp, tomcat, mod-proxy-ajp

I have a application which has apache and tomcat configured using mod_proxy_ajp
We have configured it in httpd.conf as below:

```
# This is to redirect any request which is coming with hostname to   Login.jsp
RewriteRule ^/$ /jsp/Login.jsp [R]

#include httpd-proxy.conf
<IfModule mod_proxy_ajp.c>
 Include conf/extra/httpd-proxy.conf
</IfModule>
```

Into httpd-proxy.conf following is the proxy configuration:

```
<Proxy *>
  AddDefaultCharset Off
  Order deny,allow
  Allow from all
</Proxy>
ProxyPass /jsp/ ajp://localhost:8009/jsp/
ProxyPassReverse /jsp/ ajp://localhost:8009/jsp/
```

in server.xml file for tomcat we have configured AJP connector as below:

```
 <Connector port="8009" protocol="org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProtocol" redirectPort="8443" address="localhost" 
        enableLookups="true" maxThreads="500" connectionTimeout="120000" URIEncoding="UTF-8" />
```

Now when i access my machine with host name and ip address the request works fine and Login.jsp is displayed. 
However if i add an entry into hosts file on both server as well as client(from where browser is running) with some alias to original server name as below then it doesn't work.

```
    some_ip_address original_host_name  alias1 #This is alias
```

The request is redirected to Login.jsp when I make request as http://alias1 but the page is not coming up. 
In browser i can see the url as http://alias1/jsp/Login.jsp but page is not coming up.
In apache ajp logs I can see response code is 200. So not sure where exactly is the problem
Can anybody please help me

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you have used the normal mod_proxy before trying ajp, if not you should try that.

Here is an example code for adding a Virtual Host that will serve pages from Apache for the same domain and port and will redirect to a Tomcat instance for a specific Alias

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot "d:/apache_test/htdocs/webapp"
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPass /tomcatapp http://localhost:8080/tomcatapp
    ProxyPassReverse /tomcatapp http://localhost:8080/tomcatapp

</VirtualHost>
```

Using this the actual URL at the top won't change to that with Tomcat's port, but your requests will be forwarded. If required add URL mapping for specific /path in your web.xml also to further segregate requests.